# VBA WinHTTP Auto detect proxy settings

Tags: excel, httpwebrequest, http-proxy, winhttp, vba

I am trying to send request to a web service from behind a proxy server in excel vba. How can i make my code auto detect proxy settings?

```
Url = "www.example.com"

Set WHTTP = CreateObject("WinHTTP.WinHTTPrequest.5.1")

WHTTP.Open "GET", Url, False

WHTTP.Send

MsgBox WHTTP.Status
MsgBox WHTTP.ResponseText
MsgBox WHTTP.ResponseBody
MsgBox WHTTP.GetAllResponseHeaders

Set WHTTP = Nothing

End Sub
```